# I'm getting "Thin content with little or no added value"... I think I'm the exception?

Tags: youtube-api, google-ads-api, google-search-console

I'm getting this message on google webmaster tools for my website YouGamePlay.com

"Thin content with little or no added value
This site appears to contain a significant percentage of low-quality or shallow pages which do not provide users with much added value (such as thin affiliate pages, cookie-cutter sites, doorway pages, automatically generated content, or copied content)."

The site was created to help promote authors of gameplay videos/channels. I'm using YouTube API to power the site. My site has comments, leaderboards, aids the user in locating similar videos and channels.

The site is NOT a cookie cutter site, because.... videos obtain a score, there are video leaderboards, channels, top players/viewers,comments etc.

Could someone explain or tell me why my site is being denied promotion via Google Webmaster Tools? Its very frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: This question needs to be asked of google.

Comment: Yep. Its a little difficult to get in touch with them :)

Comment: @MeteKamil How did you fix this problem? I am also troubled by the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3-obcXkyA4. The home page could be treated as a "Doorway", try adding a description for each item.